# Axon 4.0 with Kafka. Event not processed second service

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, event-sourcing, axon

As stated above we are using Axon (AxonFramework 4.0) with Kafka.
We have two services:

> ServiceA
>
> ServiceB

A common library was created to hold `events`
In this case just one simple POJO

`@Revision(1.0)
class DummyEvent(val id: String, val value: String)`

This library `common.jar` is a dependency to both `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`

application.yml for both is nearly identical

```html
axon:
  kafka:
    default-topic: axon-events
    producer:
      retries: 5
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      transaction-id-prefix: efcstx
    consumer:
      group-id: external-sync-group
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  distributed:
    enabled: true
  serializer:
    messages: jackson
  eventhandling:
    processors:
      common:
        mode: tracking
        source: kafkaMessageSource
```

When DummyEvent is fired from ServiceA we can see it published to Kafka and it can be consumed by @EventHandler in ServiceA. ServiceB fails to handle the event.

Same behavior is observed when the event is fired from ServiceB. The event is successfully published to Kafka and can be consumed by @EventHandler in ServiceB but fails to be processed in ServiceA.

We've tried multiple serialization approaches including the one seen above. Please advise any way you can.

Comment: I've reproduced the problem where you can observe the source: (https://github.com/mishkaechoes/axon-demo)

Comment: So, you've established that the event has been put on the topic, that's good. Have you also verified it's received by the component in Service B? I'd add some debugging logic to figure that out.

If not, something might be wrong in the configuration of the receiving side of your application, thus Service B.
Additionally, if you'd use the (free) AxonServer plan, you do not have to bother with any configuration like this. It'll do the routing quite easily actually.

Comment: Resolved. Going to upload a solution.

Comment: @Mishka: Once you did, please answer your own question, I would be interested as well. Thanks

Comment: @JanGalinski My recommendation is to create a shared jar with Event definitions removing the risk of different namespaces for the events. That's requirement number 1.

The second trick is to add `@ProcessingGroup("serviceB")` around the component you wish to `@EventHandler`.

In the` application.yml or properties have the following:
`eventhandling:
    processors:
      serviceB:
        mode: tracking
        source: kafkaMessageSource`
So you define the processor and then decorate a component with it.